# Audio seems not work with CallKit when incoming call is answered

Tags: ios, swift, voip, avaudiosession, callkit

I integrated my app with `CallKit` in order to receive incoming call from another user using `VoIP`. Now i am facing some issue with audio which it cannot be activated when call is answered.

I have checked with this tutorial [This](https://github.com/opentok/CallKit/blob/master/CallKitDemo/ProviderDelegate.swift) and i have compared `ProviderDelegate` which is quite similar.

This is how my `ProviderDelegate` class looks like

```
class ProviderDelegate: NSObject {
// 1.
fileprivate let callKitManager: CallKitCallInit
fileprivate let provider: CXProvider

init(callKitManager: CallKitCallInit) {
    self.callKitManager = callKitManager
    // 2.
    provider = CXProvider(configuration: type(of: self).providerConfiguration)
    
    super.init()
    // 3.
    provider.setDelegate(self, queue: nil)
    
}

// 4.
static var providerConfiguration: CXProviderConfiguration {
    let providerConfiguration = CXProviderConfiguration(localizedName: "vKclub dev2")
    
    providerConfiguration.supportsVideo = false
    providerConfiguration.maximumCallsPerCallGroup = 1
    providerConfiguration.supportedHandleTypes = [.phoneNumber]
    return providerConfiguration
}

func reportIncomingCall(uuid: UUID, handle: String, hasVideo: Bool = false, completion: ((NSError?) -> Void)?) {
    // 1.
    print("This is UUID === ", uuid)
    configureAudioSession()
    let update = CXCallUpdate()
    update.remoteHandle = CXHandle(type: .phoneNumber, value: handle)
    update.hasVideo = hasVideo
    

    provider.reportNewIncomingCall(with: uuid, update: update) { error in
        
        
        if error == nil {
            
            self.configureAudioSession()
            let call = CallKitCallInit(uuid: uuid, handle: handle)
            self.callKitManager.add(call: call)
            lastCallUUID = uuid
            print("UUID === ", uuid)
        } else {
            
        }
        
       
        completion?(error as NSError?)
    }
    
    
}

}
```

This is how i setup `AVAudioSession`

```
extension ProviderDelegate: CXProviderDelegate {

func providerDidReset(_ provider: CXProvider) {
    print("Stop Audio ==STOP-AUDIO==")
    
    for call in callKitManager.calls {
        call.end(uuid: UUID())
    }
    
    callKitManager.removeAllCalls()
}
func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXStartCallAction) {
    // 1.
    guard let call = callKitManager.callWithUUID(uuid: action.callUUID) else {
        action.fail()
        return
    }
    
    configureAudioSession()
    
}
func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXAnswerCallAction) {
    // 1.
    guard let call = callKitManager.callWithUUID(uuid: action.callUUID) else {
        action.fail()
        return
    }
    // 2.
    configureAudioSession()
    // 3.
    call.answer()
    // 4.
    if #available(iOS 11, *) {
        print ("vKclub")
    } else {
        
        action.fulfill()
    }
    
}

func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXEndCallAction) {
    // 1.
    guard let call = callKitManager.callWithUUID(uuid: action.callUUID) else {
        action.fail()       
        return
    }
    // 2.
    print("Stop audio ==STOP-AUDIO==")
    configureAudioSession()
    // 3.
    call.end(uuid: action.callUUID)
    // 4.
    if #available(iOS 11, *) {
        print("Our vKclube")
    } else {
        action.fulfill()
    }
    
    // 5.
    callKitManager.remove(call: call)
}

// 5.
func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, didActivate audioSession: AVAudioSession) {
    print("Starting audio ==STARTING-AUDIO==")
}


func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, didDeactivate audioSession: AVAudioSession) {
    print("Received \(#function)")
}

func configureAudioSession() {
    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    do{
        try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord,
                                 mode: AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat,
                                 options: [])

    } catch {
        print("========== Error in setting category \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    
    do {
        try session.setPreferredSampleRate(44100.0)
    } catch {
        print("======== Error setting rate \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    do {
        try session.setPreferredIOBufferDuration(0.005)
    } catch {
        print("======== Error IOBufferDuration \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    do {
        try session.setActive(true)
    } catch {
        print("========== Error starting session \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

}

I have been facing this issue for several days already still i cannot figure it out.
I am using XCode 10.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the error is about your code `action.fulfill()` is never called.

Based on document of Apple:

**Calling this method sets the isComplete property value to true. Calling this method more than once or calling it after calling the fail() method has no effect.
You should only call this method from the implementation of a CXProviderDelegate method.**

I hope you should call this method inside CXProviderDelegate. I have seen you implemented it but sadly that method is never called. I am sure this is the reason why your audio is not activated.